# How to cache PFUser locally if it fails to sign up due to internet failure?

Tags: xcode, swift, parse-platform

My app creates a PFUser in order to differentiate each sending devices. I am not using `PFUser.enableautomaticuser()` for some technical reason.

Also, I am using local datastore by calling `Parse.enableLocalDatastore()`

When internet is down and app fails to sign up using

```
user.signUpInBackgroundWithBlock()
```

it won't save this user locally either. The created `PFUser` is discarded, calling `PFUser.currentUser()` returns `nil`.

Then how to cache created user locally when internet is unavailable? Thank you very much!

Comment: How can you sign up to an Internet driven platform without the internet? Simply stop the users from progressing until they can successfully sign up with adequate Internet, can't log onto Facebook or Twitter without the internet much less sign up for it. But to answer your question _how to cache created user_ , you can't. Because the user hasn't been created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using `PFUser.enableautomaticuser()` and then make changes to `PFUser.currentUser()`.

At last I will attempt to `signUp`, if failed, I will call `saveEventually()` so that next user logs in. They will retain the previous `PFUser` reference, so that their information won't be lost in case the user starts the application without internet.